# Steiner Tree Approximation

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm, trees

I am wondering about the existence of Mathematica code to find (approximate) [Steiner trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem) in graphs.  I know there are a number of algorithms to do so --- just curious if anyone has implemented any of these in a Mathematica context.

The graphs I'm interested in have at most 300 vertices.  I'd also be curious to know if anyone has implemented (in Mathematica) an exact algorithm that runs for that many vertices in less than a lifetime.

Comment: The most reasonable way to accomplish this in Mathematica is to look for integer programming formulations and implement them with `LinearProgramming`

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and I found this on github. Seems to work rather well for my problem.

https://github.com/spefk/wolfram_steiner/commits?author=spefk